# Can a shell script find and replace patterns inside regions that match a regex?

Tags: awk, sed, scripting

I want to write a shell command that replaces all newlines from all paragraphs in `stdout` that match a specific regex with spaces. Here, I'm defining a paragraph to be any text bookended by two or more new lines.

Specifically, I want to locate all paragraphs of text that do not begin with `(` or `$` and strip these paragraphs of all newlines.

For example, running my script on

```
Aliquam erat volutpat.  Nunc ( eleifend leo vitae magna.  In (i)yd erat non orci
commodo lobortis.  Proin $ neque massa, cursus ut, gravida ut, lobortis eget,
lacus.  Sed diam.

Hello world.

(Nullam tristique diam
non turpis.



Hello
$again!

$foo
bar
```

should result in

```
Aliquam erat volutpat.  Nunc ( eleifend leo vitae magna.  In (i)yd erat non orci commodo lobortis.  Proin $ neque massa, cursus ut, gravida ut, lobortis eget, lacus.  Sed diam.

Hello world.

(Nullam tristique diam
non turpis.



Hello $again!

$foo
bar
```

Is this possible?

I don't mind if there's collateral damage like adding extra newlines (but I'm also curious if it can be done without collateral damage!).

Comment: Difficult if you're restricted to a single command. Languages like `perl` or `emacs` can handle this easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As extra blank lines don't matter

```
gawk 'BEGIN {RS=""} !/^[$(]/ {gsub("\n"," ")} {print;print "\n"}'
```

Explanation. `RS=""` sets gawk into paragraph mode. `!/^[$(]/` matches paragraphs that don't start with `(` or `$`. `gsub("\n"," ")` changes newlines into spaces. `print;print "\n"` outputs the data and a newline.

Comment: With gawk, you could use `{printf "%s%s",$0,RT}` to preserve the exact paragraph separation I think?

Answer (score 6):

Using any awk in any shell on all Unix boxes:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'\n' '!/^[($]/{$1=$1} 1' file
Aliquam erat volutpat.  Nunc ( eleifend leo vitae magna.  In (i)yd erat non orci commodo lobortis.  Proin $ neque massa, cursus ut, gravida ut, lobortis eget, lacus.  Sed diam.

Hello world.

(Nullam tristique diam
non turpis.

Hello $again!

$foo
bar
```

The above will print a blank line after every paragraph, including the last one in the file even if it didn't have one originally. If that's an issue let us know as it's easy to not do so.

Comment: Any idea why omitting `-F'\n'` slightly changes the output even though [the specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) says a null `RS` causes the field separator to always be a newline?

Comment: @Quasímodo null RS doesn't cause the field separator to **be** a newline, it causes it to **include** a newline. It still also includes blank and tab (or whatever else the FS is set to if it's a single char).

Comment: Oh, that's it. Quoting verbatim: "The newline shall always be a field separator." So the newline being *a* field separator does not mean it is the only one. What a tricky wording in the specification!

Comment: Right and  the current version of the POSIX spec is unfortunately wrong where it says `a <newline> shall always be a field separator, no matter what the value of FS is` but that's not quite true, it should end with `...if FS is a single char` as that's how all awks actually berhave. I'm pretty sure I have a bug report open against the spec about that, let me check...

Comment: @Quasímodo Ah, now I remember - I had raised the issue with the gawk providers (see https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2019-04/msg00029.html) and THEY were going to follow up with the standards folks to get it fixed there. Unfortunately at that point I lost interest and didn't pursue the standard change, I expect it is in the queue somewhere.

Comment: @Quasímodo I see that functionality and bug in the spec is now specifically addressed in the gawk manual (https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Multiple-Line): `When RS is set to the empty string and FS is set to a single character, the newline character always acts as a field separator. This is in addition to whatever field separations result from FS....Note that language in the POSIX specification implies that this special feature should apply when FS is a regexp. However, Unix awk has never behaved that way, nor has gawk. This is essentially a bug in POSIX.`

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>GNU sed</kbd>

Store the paragraph in the hold space.
This method will preserve multiple empty lines.

```
sed -e '
  /./,/^$/!b
  H;/./{$!d;}
  z;x;s/.//;$!s/.$//
  /^[$(]/!y/\n/ /
  $!G
' file
```

---

```
perl -pl -00e '
  y/\n/ / unless /^[$(]/;
  s/$/\n/ unless eof;
' file
```

Perl in paragraph mode `-00`. The consecutive empty lines will be collapsed into one.